# The connection between target groups, containers and host ports [Verifying my Understanding]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

The following question came to my mind some time ago:

> Why do we link *target groups* with *containers* in the load balancer
> section when creating a service? Wouldn't it be more logical to try
> linking target groups with a *host port* and then, at some point, map
> the host port to the appropriate container port. I am contemplating
> this because the traffic between a load balancer and a container
> within a task **always** flows through a host port on a computing
> resource.

After researching the topic for some time, I came up with the following answer to this question. However, since I am new to AWS, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could confirm the accuracy of this information. Any insights or feedback are highly appreciated!

---

Consider the following points:

1. At a high conceptual level, containers within a task are packaged programs, and like any other program, they require a set of machines to run on. Therefore, there is a natural connection between containers (and underlying container ports) and target groups. It is thus very expected to associate containers with target groups when defining a service.
2. That being said, in the real world, load balancers direct traffic to a host port on a computing machine, and that traffic needs to be forwarded to the appropriate container port inside the computing machine. Therefore, for the process to work properly, there is a need to establish an intermediary host port at some point. There are two ways to achieve this:

   (a) Automatic: We have the option not to specify any host port anywhere. In that case, AWS automatically assigns a (valid) port number on our behalf. (Note that the specific choice of port number really does not matter).

   (b) Manual: We have the option to specify a select port number for the connection between load balancers and containers, if we want to. This can be achieved in two ways: (i) In the port mapping section of the container within a **task definition**. (ii) By [specifying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-target-group.html#:%7E:text=(Optional)%20For%20Protocol%20and%20Port%2C%20modify%20the%20default%20values%20as%20needed.) a port when defining a target group. When the target group is later linked to a container (and container port) in a **[service definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html#:%7E:text=For%20Application%20Load%20Balancers%20and%20Network%20Load%20Balancers%2C%20this%20object%20must%20contain%20the%20load%20balancer%20target%20group%20ARN%2C%20the%20container%20name%20(as%20it%20appears%20in%20a%20container%20definition)%2C%20and%20the%20container%20port%20to%20access%20from%20the%20load%20balancer.)**, the selected host port will be used. (If there is any conflict between methods (i) and (ii), I believe method (ii) takes priority).
3. When using the Fargate launch type, we do not directly deal with computing machines. Therefore, the automatic option mentioned earlier makes much more sense. In fact, option 2a is [not available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_portmappings:%7E:text=For%20task%20definitions%20that%20use%20the%20awsvpc%20network%20mode%2C%20only%20specify%20the%20containerPort.%20The%20hostPort%20can%20be%20left%20blank%20or%20it%20must%20be%20the%20same%20value%20as%20the%20containerPort.) at all, and option 2b may not be available either (I am not sure). On a related note, for the Fargate launch type, the target type [must always be "IP"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-application-load-balancer.html#:%7E:text=If%20your%20service%27s%20task%20definition%20uses%20the%20awsvpc%20network%20mode%20(which%20is%20required%20for%20the%20Fargate%20launch%20type)%2C%20you%20must%20choose%20IP%20addresses%20as%20the%20target%20type%20This%20is%20because%20tasks%20that%20use%20the%20awsvpc%20network%20mode%20are%20associated%20with%20an%20elastic%20network%20interface%2C%20not%20an%20Amazon%20EC2%20instance.); it cannot be "Instance."